# Find the most repeated word in a string

Tags: java

can you give me some pointers as of how can I find the most frequent word in an String? I cannot use Maps, lists or so on. I should only achieve this by for's and if's and some in-build methods.

Comment: 1) Remove punctuation 2) split sentence by spaces 3) map of words -> frequency 4) iterate map, get key with highest value

Comment: @Michael _... I cannot use Maps..._

Comment: Maybe you could sort your array (after splitting the string) and count adjacent words, resetting on word changes, and looking for the max of repeats

Comment: @Michael I cannot use maps.

Comment: @Uponn Ah, one of those poorly designed assignments that forces arbitrary constraints on students because they couldn't come up with an exercise that's actually appropriate for the material that they're teaching. Good luck with that!

Comment: If the words in the string are separated by space then use String.split() to make an array of words. For each word count how often it is the array.

Comment: @Ralf Renz yea, I've though about this but afterwards how would I display the most repeated word?

Comment: @uponn I have posted my answer see if that helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split String and save to array, sort the array, iterate over the sorted array and count frequency of same strings updating the maximal count. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myStr = "how can I find the most frequent word in an string how can I find how how how string";
    String[] splited = myStr.split(" ");
    Arrays.sort(splited);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splited));
    int max = 0;
    int count= 1;
    String word = splited[0];
    String curr = splited[0];
    for(int i = 1; i<splited.length; i++){
        if(splited[i].equals(curr)){
            count++;
        }
        else{
            count =1;
            curr = splited[i];
        }
        if(max<count){
            max = count;
            word = splited[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max + " x " + word);
}
```

Comment: You can probably move `if(max<count){` into the `else` block.

Comment: Does not handel equal frequency. If there are strings with equal frequency only the first string is returned.

Comment: @Uponn How this answer is the best ?? Arrays IE being used and this is case insensitive operation ?? I though you said not to use Array or related classes ?

Answer (score 1):

Sample idea (there are thousand ways to solve this):

1: A B B C B (< String with words, seperated by blanks)
   'A' is your start position

2: count the A (1) and save the pos of A (0). You always iterate from `pos` until the end of the String.

3: continue counting until you iterated over the entire String. When you reached the end of the String save the count by assigning it to another variable (e.g. oldCount).

4: move on to the next word and start counting B's (new position = 1). You are about to count 3 B's. If newer count > older count replace the older count.

5: count the next word and update the position to your current position, which is 3. (which is the last position of the String).

6: you are not gonna update the counter, B is the most used word in the String.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String...strings) {
        String para = "Paris in the the spring.Not that that is related.Why are you laughing? Are my my regular expressions THAT bad??";
        String[] words = para.split("\\s+");
        int finalCount = 0;
        int tempCount = 0;
        String mostlyUsedWord = null;
        for (String word: words) {
            tempCount = 0;
            for (String w: words) {
                if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(w)) {
                    tempCount++;
                }
            }
            if (tempCount >= finalCount) {
                finalCount = tempCount;
                mostlyUsedWord = word;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("mostlyUsedWord:: = " + mostlyUsedWord + " ,count:: = " + finalCount);
    }
```

Comment: This will gives "that" as the result, the search is case insensitive

Comment: I think Pattern is a bit oversized here. Why not use an inner loop and String.equals?

Comment: Thanks, it most likely words but as I said I have to use only for loops, if statements and some inbuild methods (indexOf, compare, isEqual and etc.). We still haven't learned about Pattern and Matcher so I have no idea what they do at the moment.

Comment: @Hades I've picked the other answer as best because we still haven't learned for-each which you've used. The other answer is easy enough for me to understand what is happening also.

Comment: @Uponn but you explicitly mentioned not to use List , I havent , anyways whatever works for you.

Comment: moreover my answer is case insensitive if that's what you might be looking for , the answer you accepted is not

Answer (score 0):

For the purists - just loops and `String`.

```
private String mostFrequentWord(String words) {
    // Where my current word starts.
    int wordStart = 0;
    // How many I counted.
    int wordCount = 0;
    // The currently most frequent.
    String word = "";
    for (int wordEnd = wordStart; wordEnd < words.length(); wordEnd++) {
        // Is this the end of a word?
        if (wordEnd > words.length() || words.charAt(wordEnd) == ' ') {
            // We have a word! How many times does it occur?
            String thisWord = words.substring(wordStart, wordEnd);
            // How many times this word occurs.
            int thisWordCount = 0;
            // Current start of search.
            int search = -1;
            // Count them.
            while ((search = words.indexOf(thisWord, search + 1)) >= 0) {
                thisWordCount += 1;
            }
            // Is it longer?
            if (thisWordCount > wordCount) {
                // Keep track.
                word = thisWord;
                wordCount = thisWordCount;
            }
            // Move start to the next word.
            wordStart = wordEnd + 1;
        }
    }
    return word;
}

private void test() {
    String words = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party";
    System.out.println("Most frequent word in \"" + words + "\" is " + mostFrequentWord(words));
}
```